# ionic serve gives error

Tags: cordova, google-chrome, ionic-framework, ionic-popup

I am not very new to ionic framework. I used to develop small applications. But suddenly some unknown reason I am not able to run any of my application now. I have even created a 'blank' project and tried to run application using 'ionic serve' command. It loads nothing in the browser (chrome). I have found the following error in the console log.

```
 GET http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/css/ionic.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
 (index):51 GET http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js       net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
 app.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
 controllers.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
 services.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
```

and also the I have found something like javascript.js failed load error in network tab

I have tried to ran the application in chrome,chrome canary & incognito windows. 
I have even uninstalled the ionic/clear the cache and installed everything again but results were same.

I am using the following stack:
node :   v0.12.2
ionic:   1.3.18
cordova: 4.3.0

Can some one please let me know what could be went wrong? and what else I should try?

Answer (score 0):

try running an ionic project in the intel xdk, it has a built in emulator that works a lot better for testing your project. You can find the intel xdk here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/tools. it even has a started template for ionic projects. It has built in text editor, debugger, test server (so you can preview your apps on your devices without having to install), and build service. I also had some issues with the ionic cli but intel xdk makes everything super simple. Best of luck